# Initializing a std::vector in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, linker, stdvector

I get linker errors when compiling the following code:

Here the header file:

```
// Solver.h

#ifndef SOLVER_H_
#define SOLVER_H_

#include <vector>
#include "Resource.h"
#include "ValueFunction.h"

template<typename T>
class Solver {
    public:
        Solver(std::vector<Resource>& resources);
    private:
        std::vector<T> valfuncs;
};

#endif /* SOLVER_H_ */
```

And here the source file:

```
// Solver.cpp

#include "Solver.h"

template<typename T>
Solver<T>::Solver(std::vector<Resource>& resources) : 
    valfuncs(resources.size()) {}

// Explicit class declaration
template class Solver<ValueFunction>;
```

And the call:

```
// openadp.cpp

#include "Solver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<Resource> resources(4);
    Solver<ValueFunction> sol(resources);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is compiling fine if I remove `valfuncs(resources.size())` from the initialization list. Why is it not possible to initialize the vector with the class passed from my template list?

Thanks in advance,
Reza

**Update**

Sorry, but this mini-example does not reproduce the error!
I'm trying to find one which does.

**Update 2**

The linker error was due to a wrong order of includes in my cmake files.

**Remark**

This question is not a duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) first, because (the most obvious) the code compiles and second, there is an implicite instantiation of the `Solver` template: `template class Solver<ValueFunction>;`, thus the compiler is aware of an instance of the defined type.

Comment: http://ideone.com/Z9SeH please post full minimal code that exibits the problem.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the errors you get?

Comment: @KerrekSB Completely unrelated. The template is explicitly instantiated in the TU in which it’s defined.

Comment: –1: The code compiles for me once I remove the unnecessary header includes, define all the classes and include `<vector>`. **Please post a complete working example.** Furthermore, what compiler are you using, how are you calling the compiler, and what errors do you get?

Comment: @Reza I compiled the code on gcc 4.7, but using empty `ValueFunction` and `Resources` classes.

Comment: This question can be closed but it is **NOT** a duplicate of the mentioned questions. Please refer to this [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14272/).

Comment: @Reza - rather than linking to an article, can you explain clearly in your question why this is not a duplicate. If you do that, flag again and I'll re-open.